# Magento lose layouts after moving website to another server

Tags: php, magento, layout

I developed the site on the local server, and after I moved the site to another server, Magento doesn't show layouts. They do not exist on the layout dropdown in admin panel.

What could be the problem?

Comment: what do u mean by layout?? Can you add the image of the issue that u face on the frontend? So that it will be helpful for finding the solution to explain the issue

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to migrate Magento Installation within different server.

Step 1: Create Full DataBase Dump of your current installation.

Step 2: Import your data base to your new server.

Step3: Create a zip of your current source code.

Step4: Upload it via FTP and after upload Unzip it.

Step5: Give proper file and folder permissions. [*]

Step6: Navigate to your installation root. Then go app/etc. open the file local.xml in text editor. Changes the data base details here. host,user,password,dbname in the xml.

Step7: Open your database. open the table called core_config_data. you have run two mysql update query here.

1 . UPDATE core_config_data SET `value` = `http://yournewdomain.com` WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'

2 . UPDATE core_config_data SET `value` = `http://yournewdomain.com` WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url'

Note: IF your path is like www.domain.com/source then add a slash at the end like www.domain.com/source/

Comment: After the transfer site is working normally. Consequently, I have correctly followed all the points in this list. But layouts for some reason disappeared!

Comment: did you checked the file / folder permission ?? is it correct?

Comment: yes.. I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: data base table count on your local and server are equal??

Comment: All identical, site works fine. Only layouts has disappeared.